# What do we call a "manuscript expert"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, old-english, middle-english

Someone (in most cases an academic) who is well-rounded in the field of ancient manuscripts, with solid training in history and/or literature, one or more ancient languages, paleography, and codicology. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't ***[palaeographer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paleographer)*** fit in your context?

Palaeography:

> - The study and scholarly interpretation of earlier, especially ancient, writing and forms of writing.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

I would think "philologist" is more apt.

Philology -- the study of literary texts and of written records, the establishment of their authenticity and their original form, and the determination of their meaning.

Comment: Copied definitions should include a citation.